# Boostrap 3 modal dialogue to external URL not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

My bootstrap to load a URL in a modal dialogue isnt working, can anyone help me please?

http://www.bootply.com/121350

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into same origin policy issues. Bootstrap uses jQuery .load() to load the "remote" content, but it must be on the same domain. It will work fine for a page on the same domain.

See this thread: [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: thanks, the page I want to embed looks like it is taking countermeasures against me when I run the java console; thanks for pointing me to that resource.